# How to have a Form from another Model inside a DetailView in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm working with Django and what I want to do is to have a DetailView of Posts, and inside that detail view I want a comments section with a form for posts comments. When I load the detail view it doesn't show me the form of Comments I'm using Class Based Views for the Detail of the form.
My models.py looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
text = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
tags = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '' )

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_list')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Comments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

The views.py looks like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    form_class = CommentsForm
    model = Post
```

The form looks like this:

```
   class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Comments
            fields = ('text',)

            widgets = {
                'text' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'comment-textarea'})
            }
```

And the comments_form.html looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h1>Estoy siendo insertado</h1>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn mt-2 btn-comments" value="Comment">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `DetailView` does not handle the `form_class`. You have a few options here:

- provide the form via `get_context_data`
- apply the `FormMixin` on the `DetailView`. (Can be found under `django.view.generic.edit`)

Context data example:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments_form'] = CommentsForm()
    return context
```

Comment: But I need the Comments Model for the comments_from, where can I declare the Comments Model withot removing the Post model?

Comment: @PaulMiranda since the `DetailView` is dedicated to the `Post` model, you need to handle the `Comment` model and `CommentsForm` form manually via `get_context_data` and the best practice for the comment form should be that you post to a `CommentsView` rather than the `PostDetailView`. It does not make sense to post comments on a post view.

Comment: @PaulMiranda does it make sense?

Comment: I used FormMixin and it worked, but when a press the button for comment it doesn't save it, you know why this can be?

Comment: @PaulMiranda yes, as I have said your `PostDetailView` is dedicated to `Post`'s not `Comment`'s. Also because `FormView` is not enough to handle the `post` operation of the form. Check the [django source code for the FormView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L129) to understand better why. Hint: you are not using this and it should be possible to put both the `DetailView` and `FormView` as mixins on the same class.